# Python: Is there a quick way to break out of all functions? Return to main loop?

Tags: python

Quick example:

```
def func_1():
    func_2()

def func_2():
    func_3()

def func_3():
    #Finds condition to end all calculations and break of out all functions

func_1()
```

I have some code with functions running other functions running other functions all together doing a lot of time consuming audio calculations. I have a "stop test" tkinter button that I want to stop all testing with, but for that to happen, all functions has be broken out of. Is there a quick way to do this? To check for a stop condition would require butloads of IF-statements as the stop conditon can be set at any time during the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's built-in exception mechanism to do this.  If you are going to go this route, I recommend a custom, well-named exception.

```
class JumpToMainLoop(Exception):
    pass

def func_1():
    func_2()

def func_2():
    func_3()

def func_3():
    raise JumpToMainLoop

try:
    func_1()
except JumpToMainLoop:
    pass
```

Using a built-in exception (like `ValueError`) or worse a generic exception (like `Exception`) is not desirable since other things that can go wrong would be caught and missed by your `try: except:`.

Comment: Please take a look at the following link if this helped you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use exceptions

```
def func_1():
    func_2()

def func_2():
    func_3()

def func_3():
    if condition:
        raise Exception('something happened')

try:
    func_1()
except Exception:
    pass
```